# Update UILabel text when a NSString is changed in another class

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uilabel, nsobject

I have a `NSObject` class with `NSStrings` and `UIImages`. I fill them by downloading data from a server. What I do in a manager class, I download a JSON and parse it into the `NSObject` to fill the basic `NSString` & `UIImages`. Then I launch a method in the `NSObject`'s class to download the more complex data from another server and put the `NSObject` into a `NSMutableDictionary`. So what I end up with is a dictionary full of my `NSObjects`, with some data already downloaded and some data still downloading.

Then I try to feed the data of the `NSObject` into `UILabels`, and `UIImageViews` in another class (view controller). However, some of the data will probably still be loading so their so the UILabels would show up empty if for example the `NSString` that should fill it wouldn't be downloaded yet.

Now my question is, how can I change the `UILabels`'s text again, once the `NSString` in it's `NSObject` class has been downloaded (re-set)? Basically I'd need to "observe" the `NSObject`'s `NSString`'s value from the `UILabel`'s class. I've found something like this:

```
observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context
```

But I have no idea how to use it. I know I'd have to implement it in the `UILabel`'s class, but how, and how do I set it to update the `UILabel`'s text when it observes a change in the `NSObject`'s `NSString`?

Also I've read something about a `NSObjectController` class, is it applicable here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to implement the following in your `UILabel` subclass:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"nameOfThePropertyInYourNSObjectSubclass"]) {
        id changedValue = [object valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
        //do what ever you want with it
    }
}
```

Also to register your `NSObject` subclass for KVO, you need to implement:

```
[self addObserver:yourUILabel forKeyPath:@"nameOfThePropertyOfYourString" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

Note that you also have to unregister the observer at the appropriate time (depending on your design):

```
[self removeObserver:yourUILabel forKeyPath:@"nameOfThePropertyOfYourString" context:NULL];
```

Also note, that, while KVO is a neat thing and quite useful in some cases, it's be no means a no brainer to choose it. Especially in your case I would recommend to use a callback instead. Fetching data from the network is best done in a background thread, in that case I would use a delegate pattern to inform your view controller, that new data is available and let the view controller take care of updating your labels.

Comment: Okay, but will it still work when I have multiple NSObjects and I want to feed their data to lets say a UITableView? How do I make sure that one NSString is really hooked up to that one UILabel? And whats the delegate method then?

Comment: take a look at the various apple delegate patterns. The target-action pattern for example. You can have many `UIButtons` connected to one `IBAction`. Each `UIButton` then hands itself as an argument to the callback, so the delegate can then decide what to do. When you setup your `NSObjects` you could keep an additional `NSDictionary` that connects the objects to the `UILabels`. Take a look at [Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html) it's really worth reading it

Comment: Hmm okay... So basically the NSObject would be the delegate of the placeholder view (lets say a UITableViewCell or UIView). But it is still unclear to me, how to tell the particular NSObject from the big dictionary containing many of them to be the delegate of the particular Cell/View that shows it's data?

Comment: And also -> the view will be reusable. The data of the NSObject might be displayed when you tap a MKAnnotationView as a UIPopover.

Comment: There is always the option of creating a UITableViewCell (to present in the UITableVIew) and UIViewController (to present in the UIPopover in a mapView) for EACH NSObject. OR to create two UIView instances directly in the NSObject class, one for the tableView and one for the mapView popover. The views would contain the label layout etc.

I'll probably go with the last option if I don't find a way to do it in a more reusable manner...

Answer (score 1):

You're very close - what you want is called **key-value observing**, and it's described in detail in the [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html). You don't need an NSObjectController for this - instead, have the view controller managing the view for the UILabels add itself as an observer for the other class, then just update the UILabel text whenever you receive the `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context` message.

Answer (score 0):

KVO is possible, but also check out *delegate* pattern. I believe it would be simpler here.